# Como corrigir o erro "1452 > a foreign key constraint fails" usando PDO no PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Primeiramente eu sei o que é o erro da **foreign key**, no entanto eu não sei porque ele está acontecendo no código PHP com o PDO.

> Função de inserção:

```
function insert_pedido($cod,$pagamento,$total){

    (int)$id = $cod;

    $con = $this->connect();

    $data = date("Y/m/d");

    $DBH = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO pedido (cod_cliente, data, pagamento, total) VALUES ('?','?','?','?')");
    $DBH->bindParam(1,$id);
    $DBH->bindParam(2,$data);
    $DBH->bindParam(3,$pagamento);
    $DBH->bindParam(4,$total);
    if($DBH->execute()){

        return 1;

    }else{

        print_r($DBH->errorInfo());

    }

}
```

> Faço a chamada da função passando estes parâmetros

```
$cod = $_POST["cod_cliente"];
$pagamento = $_POST["pagamento"];
$total = $_POST["total"];
```

E a chamada da função

```
insert_pedido($cod,$pagamento,$total);
```

Esse é o erro recebido:

Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1452 [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`empresa`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_cliente`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`cod_cliente`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) )

> Como disse antes, já verifiquei a existência do cod_cliente, já adicionei manualmente no **phpmyadmin** e deu certo.

Comment: Não vai aspas simples nas interrogações! no lugar de `(int)$id = $cod;` não seria `$id = (int) $cod;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você tenta inserir uma valor que não existe na tabela de cliente, pois ao adicionar aspas simples o placeholder(interrogação) vira um literal.

Mude:

```
INSERT INTO pedido (cod_cliente, data, pagamento, total) VALUES ('?','?','?','?')
```

para:

```
INSERT INTO pedido (cod_cliente, data, pagamento, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado, agora que você corrigiu, me fez parecer um bobo. Agora estou vacinado!